# GlobalTable creation role error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am creating a global table after creating table in multiple regions in DynamoDB through a custom resource lamda call in cloudformation. 
I pass the region name in the replicationgroup.

```
 response = client.create_global_table(GlobalTableName=TABLENAME,ReplicationGroup=replicationgroup)
```

When running this I am getting the below error

```
when calling the CreateGlobalTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Failed to assume Service Linked Role ‘AWSServiceRoleForDynamoDBReplication’. User is missing the following permissions: 'iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole'.
```

I have tried giving the iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole permission to the user but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `'iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole'` along side `'dynamodb:CreateGlobalTable'` as the Actions in your Policy should solve this problem (and worked for me when I encountered this same issue).

Here is an example policy document:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:CreateGlobalTable",
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```